# angular-cli server - how to specify default port

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using angular-cli with the `ng serve` command, how can I specify a default port so I do not need to manually pass the `--port` flag every time?

I'd like to change from the default port 4200.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

*Update for @angular/cli@9.x: and over*

In `angular.json` you can specify a port per "project"

```
"projects": {
    "my-cool-project": {
        ... rest of project config omitted
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                    "port": 1337
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All options available:

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#project-tool-configuration-options

Alternatively, you may specify the port each time when running ng serve like this:

`ng serve --port 1337`

With this approach you may wish to put this into a script in your package.json to make it easier to run each time / share the config with others on your team:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --port 1337"
}
```

---

Legacy:

*Update for @angular/cli final:*

Inside `angular-cli.json` you can specify the port in the defaults:

```
"defaults": {
  "serve": {
    "port": 1337
  }
}
```

---

Legacy-er:

*Tested in angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.22-1*

The server in `angular-cli` comes from the `ember-cli` project.
To configure the server, create an `.ember-cli` file in the project root. Add your JSON config in there:

```
{
   "port": 1337
}
```

Restart the server and it will serve on that port.

There are more options specified here:
http://ember-cli.com/#runtime-configuration

```
{
  "skipGit" : true,
  "port" : 999,
  "host" : "0.1.0.1",
  "liveReload" : true,
  "environment" : "mock-development",
  "checkForUpdates" : false
}
```

Comment: It seems that things have changed in recent versions of the CLI (I'm using version 6). [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50330606/1063392).

Answer (score 75):

In Angular 2 cli@2.3.1,

To run a new project on the different port, one way is to specify the port while you run ng serve command.

```
ng serve --port 4201
```

or the other way, you can edit your package.json file scripts part and attached the port to your start variable like I mentioned below and then simply run "npm start"

```
 "scripts": {

    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4201",
    ... : ...,
    ... : ....
}
```

this way is much better where you don't need to define port explicitly every time.

Answer (score 14):

Use npm scripts instead... Edit your package.json and add the command to script section.

```
{
  "name": "my new project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.26",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Then just execute `npm start`

Comment: This is the correct way to do this, permanently; so you don't have to specify the command-line parameter for --port every time. Also the --host param in this answer is required for running Angular 4 via Vagrant (or any remote system) so this kills 2 birds with one stone.

Answer (score 8):

You can now specify the port in the .angular-cli.json under the defaults:

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "scss",
  "serve": {
    "port": 8080
  },
  "component": {}
}
```

Tested in angular-cli v1.0.6

Comment: Thank you!!! The same thing has been tested with **@angular/cli: 1.3.0**.

Answer (score 4):

For Angular Version `12` this worked for me. In `angular.json` update like this

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-website:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-website:build:development",
              "port": 5000
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

### For @angular/cli v6.2.1

The project configuration file `angular.json` is able to handle multiple projects (workspaces) which can be individually served.

`ng config projects.my-test-project.targets.serve.options.port 4201`

Where the `my-test-project` part is the project name what you set with the `ng new` command just like here:

```
$ ng new my-test-project
$ cd my-test-project
$ ng config projects.my-test-project.targets.serve.options.port 4201
$ ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4201, open your browser on http://localhost:4201/ **
```

---

*Legacy:*

I usually use the `ng set` command to change the Angular CLI settings for project level.

```
ng set defaults.serve.port=4201
```

It changes change your .angular.cli.json and adds the port settings as [it mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154814/497057).

After this change you can use simply `ng serve` and it going to use the prefered port without the need of specifying it every time.

Comment: In Angular 6.0, I get 'set/get have been deprecated in favor of the config command', so this no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as *Angular CLI: 7.1.4*, there are two common ways to achieve **changing the default port**.

#### No. 1

In the `angular.json`, add the `--port` option to `serve` part and use `ng serve` to start the server.

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "demos:build",
    "port": 1337
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "demos:build:production"
    }
  }
},
```

#### No. 2

In the `package.json`, add the `--port` option to `ng serve` and use `npm start` to start the server.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8000",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by elwyn is correct. But you should also update protractor config for e2e.

In angular.json,

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "port": 9000,
        "browserTarget": "app:build"
      }
    }
```

In e2e/protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a situation when you want to use NodeJS environment variable to specify Angular CLI dev server port. One of the possible solution is to move CLI dev server running into a separate NodeJS script, which will read port value (e.g from .env file) and use it executing `ng serve` with `port` parameter:

```js
// run-env.js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const child_process = require('child_process');

const config = dotenv.config()
const DEV_SERVER_PORT = process.env.DEV_SERVER_PORT || 4200;

const child = child_process.exec(`ng serve --port=${DEV_SERVER_PORT}`);
child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```

Then you may a) run this script directly via `node run-env`, b) run it via npm by updating package.json, for example

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node run-env"
}
```

`run-env.js` should be committed to the repo, `.env` should not. More details on the approach can be found in this post: **[How to change Angular CLI Development Server Port via .env](https://medium.com/@dhilt/how-to-change-angular-cli-development-server-port-via-env-9335d089e469)**.