# How to change angular port from 4200 to any other

Tags: angular-cli

I want to use 5000 instead of 4200.

I have tried to create a file on root name `ember-cli` and put JSON according to the code below:

```
{
   "port": 5000
}
```

But my app still runs on 4200 instead of 5000

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port

Comment: Did u also Restart the server?

Comment: yes @kristjanreinhold

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular-cli server - how to specify default port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port)

Answer (score 233, accepted):

It seems things have changed in recent versions of the CLI (I'm using `6.0.1`).  I was able to change the default port used by `ng serve` by adding a `port` option to my project's `angular.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "projects": {
        "my-project": {
            "architect": {
                "serve": {
                    "options": {
                        "port": 4201
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Only relevant properties are shown in this example.)

Comment: And i want to change host also then

Comment: A much better answer as you don't have to worry about remembering which port to use if you have different projects open.

Answer (score 814):

The solution worked for me was

```
ng serve --port 4401
```

(You can change 4401 to whatever number you want)

Then launch browser -> http://localhost:4401/

Basically, I was having two Applications and with the help of the above approach now I am able to run both of them simultaneously in my development environment.

Comment: sidenote for others: don't do `npm start --port 4401` because `npm start` doesn't seem to execute the --port

Comment: just an addition, you can at the same time open the served app in a new browser tab by adding  `ng serve --port 4401 --open`

Comment: in package.json, look for ng serve command. Replace ng serve command as ng serve --port 5000. Then in terminal use npm start. It should work

Comment: @Jordec just to note that the correct usage would be `npm start -- --port 4401`, where the first `--` indicates start of arguments for what is triggered by `npm start`.

Answer (score 146):

You can change your application port by entering the following command,

**ng serve --port 4200**

Also, for a permanent setup you can change the port by editing angular-cli.json file

```
 "serve": {
    "options": {
      "port": 8080
    }
  }
```

Comment: In newer releases you should use ng serve --port 8080 (no ":", blank space instead).

Comment: If this is the last "defaults" setting, you should get rid of the trailing comma

Comment: This has changed in recent versions of the CLI - see my answer for more details.

Comment: `port:` has to be inside `options:`

Answer (score 97):

The location for port settings has changed a couple of times.

### If using Angular CLI 1

Change `angular-cli.json`

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5000 
    }
  }
}
```

### If using the latest Angular CLI

Change `angular.json`

```
"projects": {
    "project-name": {
        ...
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                  "host": "0.0.0.0",
                  "port": 5000
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

### Without changing any file

Run the command

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

Comment: This should be considered as the correct answer as it covers both possibilities: permanent or temporary solutions.

Comment: In case of permanent changes, do you know if the new port should be specified elsewhere in this ` angular.json` file ? My `serve` option level contains two items with `browserTarget`, `options` and `configurations/production`. Should I add this new `port` entry in both of those or just the `options` one ?

Comment: Any thought on this warning - or whatever you call it - that popup in the terminal? `Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disable-host-check" if that's the case.`

Answer (score 89):

Changing `nodel_modules/angular-cli/commands/server.js` is a bad idea as it will be updated when you install new version of `angular-cli`. Instead you should specify **ng serve --port 5000** in `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --port 5000"
}
```

You can also specify host with **--host 127.0.0.1**

Answer (score 31):

No one has updated answer for latest Angular CLI.With latest **`Angular CLI`**

With **`latest version`** of angular-cli in which angular-cli.json renamed to **`angular.json`** , you can change the port by editing **`angular.json`** file
you now specify a port per **`"project"`**

```
projects": {
    "my-cool-project": {
        ... rest of project config omitted
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                    "port": 4500
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about it  **[`here`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace)**

Answer (score 23):

To change port for once while running and no change in configuration you can use below command

```
ng serve --port 5000
```

If for every run of ng serve you need to have 5000 port. Do with below methods

1. Using angular.json

Search "serve" under that add field "options" as below:
[image]

2. In node_modules > @angular-devkit > build-angular > src > dev-server > schema.json, you will find below code and update port as you want like 5000.
   [image]
3. In package.json under "scripts" we've "start" update it with below command so on each run of "npm start" it will serve on 5000.
   [image]

*Note: Post all that restart server in terminal with 'ng serve' or 'npm start' Feedback helps to improve. Thanks!*

Answer (score 17):

For angular 10+:

1. Navigate to angular.json file.
2. Search for the "serve" field.
3. Under "serve" it will be the "options" field (if not exist add the options field).
4. Add this line to "options":
   "port": 4333(any port that you want).

Example:

```
        "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "port": 4333
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "dashboard:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 16):

I usually use the `ng set` command to change the Angular CLI settings for project level.

```
ng set defaults.serve.port=4201
```

It changes change your `.angular.cli.json` and adds the port settings as [it mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44941501/497057).

After this change you can use simply `ng serve` and it going to use the prefered port without the need of specifying it every time.

Comment: get/set appears to be deprecated in favor of config in 6.0, so this no longer works.

Answer (score 13):

you can also enter the below command in your angular cli where you normally enter npm start

**ng serve --host "ip-address" --port "port-number"**

Answer (score 10):

It is not recommended to change in node modules as updates or re-installation may remove those changes. So better to change in angular cli

Angular 9 in angular.json

```
{
    "projects": {
            "targets": {
                "serve": {
                    "options": {
                         "port": 5000
                     }
                }     
            }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

you can also write this command: `ng serve -p 5000`

Answer (score 8):

- **For Permanent:**

  Goto **nodel_modules/angular-cli/commands/server.js**
  Search for **var defaultPort = process.env.PORT || 4200;** and change 4200 to anything else you want.
- **To Run Now:**

  **ng serve --port 4500**   (You an change 4500 to any number you want to use as your port)

Comment: I don't think changing the contents of a package installed locally on `node_modules` is a good practice.

Answer (score 7):

goto this file

```
node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\schema.json
```

and search port

```
"port": {
  "type": "number",
  "description": "Port to listen on.",
  "default": 4200
},
```

change **default** value whatever you want and restart the server

Comment: Works for me, just need to notice to change the mentioned file and not the other-````node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json```` 
that contain the same property .

Comment: Generally, do not mess with node_modules! Although this solution will work temporarily, the changes will be lost as soon as @angular/devkit/build-angular gets an update

Answer (score 7):

Go to `angular.json` file,

Search for keyword "serve":

Add `port` keyword as shown below:

```
 "serve": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
     "options": {
         "browserTarget": "my-new-angular-app:build",
         "port": 3001
     },
     ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply set in package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 3000",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

then run the command

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 6):

In angular.json:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
          "browserTarget": "projectname:build",
          "port": 5000
         }
```

I am using angular-cli. This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

set your preference in package.json

> -o or --open is auto run your application in browser

> run you aplication using **npm start or ng serve**

```
"scripts": {
"start": "ng serve --port 4500 -o"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ways to change the port number in an angular project:

1. node_modules \ @angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\schema.json in this path

```
    "port": {
             "type": "number",
             "description": "Port to listen on.",
             "default": <<port number>>     /* write your required port number here */
   }
```

2. Running the project using

```
    ng serve --port <<port number>> --open
```

3. In angular.json file

```
   "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
          "browserTarget": "projectname:build",
          "port": 5000   /* add this part */
         }
```

```
adding this part and starting the server.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one enviroment, you may add the following way in the `angular.json`:

```
 "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your_project:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "your_project:build:production"
        },
        "es5": {
          "browserTarget": "your_project:build:es5"
        },
        "local": {
          "browserTarget": "your_project:build:local",
          "port": 4201
        },
        "uat": {
          "browserTarget": "your_project:build:uat"
        }
      }
    },
```

This way only the local points to another port.

Comment: That is working

Answer (score 3):

In **package.json**, look for **ng serve** command. 
Replace ng serve command as **ng serve --port 4201**. 
Then in terminal use **npm start** or **yarn start**.
It should work.

If you have more than one Angular Apps, you can specify different ports for them, and run them in the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are already numerous valid solutions in the above answers, here is a visual guide and *specific solution for Angular 7 projects* (possibly earlier versions as well, no guarantees though) using Visual Studio Code. Locate the schema.json in the directories as shown in the image tree and alter the integer under *port --> default* for a permanent change of port in the browser.

[image]

Comment: @s34N Glad to hear that. If the answer was of help, please remember to give an upvote on the post if not already done. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

We have two ways to change default port number in Angular.

First way to cli command:

```
ng serve --port 2400 --open
```

Second way is by configuration at the location: `ProjectName\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\schema.json`.

Make changes in `schema.json` file.

```
{
 "title": "Dev Server Target",
  "description": "Dev Server target options for Build Facade.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "browserTarget": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Target to serve."
    },
    "port": {
      "type": "number",
      "description": "Port to listen on.",
      "default": 2400
    },
```

Comment: It's not recommended to change files in node_modules that might be overwritten after reinstalling the package. A very good solution were presented by Sajeetharan.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit late but if still any one not want to define port with 'ng serve' can permanently change the port for application.

Edit

> angular.json

Locate

```
"serve": {
           .....
         }
```

and add bellow

```
"options": {
            "port": 9091
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NodeJS environment variable to set up the value of the port of Angular CLI dev server, following approach is possible:

- create NodeJS script, which will have an access to the environment variable (say, `DEV_SERVER_PORT`) and could run `ng serve` with `--port` parameter value taken from that variable ([child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) might be our friend here):

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');
const child = child_process.exec(`ng serve --port=${process.env.DEV_SERVER_PORT}`);
child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```

- update package.json to provide this script running via npm
- do not forget to set up `DEV_SERVER_PORT` environment variable (can be done via [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv))

Here is also the complete description of this approach: [How to change Angular CLI Development Server Port via .env](https://medium.com/@dhilt/how-to-change-angular-cli-development-server-port-via-env-9335d089e469).