# How to change defaulte localhost port in my angular app

Tags: angular

I am just starting to learn angular js. I have two apps both with deafault port of 4200, I want to have different port for each of my apps, and I don't know how to change default port.

Comment: oh, sorry, going to see that existing question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717449/how-to-change-angular-2-port-from-4200-to-any-other