# Angular 6+ How to change default port 4200

Tags: angular, port, angular-cli-v6

This question is specific to version 6 of Angular, not earlier, since **.angular-cli.json** file had been replaced by **angular.json** file.

I created a new Angular 6 project and tried, as I always did with previous versions, to change its default port but this time in angular.json.

```
  "defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "port": 4220
  },
```

But get the following error:

> Invalid schema detected in .angular-cli.json, please correct and try
>   again!

Does any one know how to do this with this new version of Angular ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli server - how to specify default port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port)

Comment: @Orlandster the mentioned question has been emitted on May 11 '16, it was talking about angular-cli, version 6 of Angular was issued on May '18, it's confusing to find such answer there.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Due to a non accurate title: "[angular-cli server - how to specify default port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port#37154814)", it was hard to find an answer to my question, but thanks to **Vladymir Gonzalez** I did.

To help others find the answer quickly, I extracted here the specific part for Angular 6, belonging to [elwyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port#37154814) :

Update for @angular/cli@6.x: In the new angular.json you now specify a port per "project"

```
"projects": {
    "my-cool-project": {
        ... rest of project config omitted
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                    "port": 4850    <-- add your custom port number here      
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All options available:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace

Comment: This can be set using the cli config command: `ng config projects.[YOURPROJECTNAME].architect.serve.options.port 1337`

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You can always specify the port while serving also: `ng serve --port 3000`

You can put any valid port number there and it will serve from that port.

Comment: I prefer to avoid this by saving the port in angular.json file, this way I can use only "ng serve -o" without trying to remember each time the port number for each app.

Comment: Makes sense, I usually have multiple projects serving with different storage/auth data so I tend to just specify when serving

Answer (score 11):

I am giving answer for **angular 2+** application.

If you wanted to start 2 angular application in different port i.e.

```
1) port 4200 
2) port 5000
```

you need to change **"package.json"** file and just change add one line **"Script block"** in first curly braces where your application name, version is default available,

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 5000 ",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Start your application by **"npm start"** command.
This command will start your application on **Port 5000**.

Comment: The best answer for long-term use so I would not have to use "ng serve --port 4300" (or another number) every time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple
write `ng serve --open  --port=YourPortNumber` in command prompt.

Example :

```
ng serve --open --port=4201
```

***==== OTHER SOLUTION ====***

You can also change it in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve --open --port=4201",
}
```

Now, in command propmt just write `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

To run angular on a specified port use command `sudo ng serve --port 8080` in place of 8080 you can specify any port number.

This will only run the project on the port number unless you close it.

Answer (score 1):

Two way to change your default port
First: using command

```
ng serve --port 8000 || ng serve --host '192.168.1.1' --port 8000
```

Second: edit your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8000",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

If you are using multiple project in some time in your system that condition first one is best and i thing first is good for practice

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running more than one angular project, you need to run the application in a different port.

By default port number: *4200*

Port number range - *1024 to 65535*

while running the project you can mention the specific port number

```
Ex : ng serve –open –port=5200
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option is:

In your package.json file,
"scripts": {
"start": "ng serve --port 5000"
}

and run this command: npm run start