# how to make protractor run constantly on the same port?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, angular-cli, e2e-testing

I wanted to run my protractor tests on the same port without changing the port number. I tried :

```
"e2e": "ng e2e --port 49152 --host localhost",
```

in the `package.jason` file and also

```
"e2e": {
  "options": {
    "port": 49152
  }
```

in the `angular.json` file but both didn't work for me. Is there any possible way to make protractor tests run in the same port?

Comment: What do you mean; what *"didn't work"*? Same port as what?

Comment: I tried changing both files but my tests still run different port numbers whenever I tried to run. So I want to run my tests in the same port to make my tests to have the same URL.

Comment: What do you mean your *tests* have the same URL? You mean the debug port? Or what?

Comment: ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49152, open your browser on http://localhost:49152/ ** I want to open my browser on http://localhost:49152/ whenever I testing using the protractor

Comment: Do you mean that you have a random port whenever you run the e2e tests?

Comment: yes, base URL is set to 4200 but it opens at random ports from time to time. So my tests fail due to the given target URL is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular-cli server - how to specify default port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port)