# ng serve: how to change inspector port?

Tags: angular, node-inspector, nrwl-nx

When I start `ng serve server` on the command line it fails with:

```
Starting inspector on localhost:7777 failed: address already in use
```

This is expected, because there is really already another instance running.

So how can I change the inspector port for this instance?

I've tried to set the env-var `NODE_OPTIONS` to

- `'--inspect=7888'`
- `'--inspect=localhost:7888'`

both had no effect: i.e. it was still failing with

```
Starting inspector on localhost:7777 failed: address already in use
```

Note: 
I **do NOT** want to change the application port: e.g. `ng serve --port 5600` - it's only about the **node-inspector port**

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port ?

Comment: @Oriol_IL no, that would change the port that the application will listen on - not the inspector port

Comment: Think inspector is backend related, not Angular therefore doesn't have anything with ng serve command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr;**

Since `ng serve server` uses `nrwl/node:execute` I must use the [nrwl port](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/12.3.x/packages/node/src/executors/execute/schema.json#L24) option:

```
ng serve server --port 7888
```

and **not** the [ng serve port](https://angular.io/cli/serve):

```
ng serve  --port 7888 server
```

**Details**:

When I start `ng serve server`, then ng will

- check the `angular.json` file for the project `server`
- in this project the `architect`-`serve` section is relevant

in my case, this is

```json
"serve": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "server:build"
  }
}
```

Thus, `ng` will just start the `@nrwl/node:execute` bulder, which supports the option [-port](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/12.3.x/packages/node/src/executors/execute/schema.json#L24)

So to summarize, there are 2 port options available

```
ng serve -port 5600 server -port 7888
```

- `5600` is the application port (which I need not chagne in this case)
- `7888` is the inspector port, which I must change in this case

Comment: I am using nx as Fullstack single repo framework and your answer help me to set the inspector port of a Nest application because it was changing on every run

"serve": {
    "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
    "options": {
        "buildTarget": "api:build",
        "inspect": true,
        "port": 9229
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

ng serve --port 4202 --host 192.175.0.48  --open

Comment: no, that will change the application port - my question is about the inspector port