# Custom domain instead of localhost - Angular

Tags: angular, custom-domain

Development purpose I want to start my Angular application with custom-domain instead of `localhost`

Is any other way available?

I am able to find solutions for **php** but I didn't find solutions for the **angular application**.

Comment: Apache + hosts file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652373/how-to-change-the-url-from-localhost-to-something-else-on-a-local-system-usin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the URL from "localhost" to something else, on a local system using wampserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652373/how-to-change-the-url-from-localhost-to-something-else-on-a-local-system-usin)

Comment: I am looking solutions with angular.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762125/set-default-host-and-port-for-ng-serve-in-config-file

Comment: you won't be able to do this in an entirely self contained fashion. You'll need other components in your environment involved, which raises the "is this worth it?" question. I have to imagine the answer is no.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update your `angular.json`

This is what you should do:

```
"projects": {
    "project-name": {
        ...
        "architect": {
            "serve": {
                "options": {
                  "host": "customdomain.baz",
                  "port": 80
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update your host file if you are on mac/ linux

go to  `/etc/hosts`

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       customdomain.baz // or whatever your domain is
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: notice that under the same path (`architect.serve.options`) there's the useful `allowedHosts` property that receives an `string[]` of domains.

Answer (score 3):

Add a line in `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   my-custom-domain.com
```

But this will require port to be specified anyway. You'll have to use `my-custom-domain.com:4200`.

To use default port `:80`, use as a reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154813/angular-cli-server-how-to-specify-default-port)

If you want to run multiple sites on the same port, but serve different domains, use Nginx or Apache as a proxy.

Here is a sample server config for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  my-custom-domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:4200;
    }
}
```